# String passing is_a? Float validation

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method that checks if an argument is a float like so:

```
  def validate_input val
    raise ArgumentError unless (val.is_a? Float)
  end
```

In my tests, I'm checking this method with:

```
  it "only accepts floating point numbers" do
    expect(c.to_rad('65A.98')).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
  end
```

But when I run rspec the test fails with

```
  1) Customer#to_rad argument is invalid only accepts floating point numbers
     Failure/Error: expect(c.to_rad('65A.98')).to raise_error(ArgumentError)
     ArgumentError:
       ArgumentError
     # ./customer.rb:54:in `validate_input'
```

I'm very new to rspec and testing so I have no idea what's going wrong. I did try to use `instance_of?` instead of `is_a?` but it produces the same result. Earlier in my tests I instantiate `c` using `c = Customer.new`. Also, I don't know if it makes a difference but I'm using ruby only. No rails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a block into `expect` so that RSpec will run the block and rescue the error. Otherwise it will run `to_rad` before the `to` is called, causing the exception to be thrown before the RSpec matcher is ever executed. Try:

```
expect { c.to_rad('65A.98') }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```